# Make datagrid selected row text colour transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers

Each row in our data grid application can have various background and foreground (text) colours.

The colors are added according to a property on the bound object called ForeColorFlag or BackColorFlag in the OnLoadingRow event according to a Dictionary using the following (similar for BackColorFlag):

```
foreach (var kvp in _foreColorFlags)
{
    var trigger = new DataTrigger {Binding = new Binding("ForeColorFlag"), Value = kvp.Key};
    var setter = new Setter(ForegroundProperty, kvp.Value);
    trigger.Setters.Add(setter);
    rowStyle.Triggers.Add(trigger);
}
```

For this reason it was necessary to hide which row was selected using the following:

```
// Remove selection style from DGV (make transparent instead of blue)
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.Transparent;
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.ControlBrushKey] = Brushes.Transparent;
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey] = Brushes.LightGray;
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey] = Brushes.LightGray;

// stop backcolor going grey when window doesn't have focus.
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.Transparent;
rowStyle.Resources[SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey] = Brushes.LightGray;
```

This means that when a row is selected its background colour is what it would be if it wasn't selected. But, unfortunately the text colour (forecolor) is forced to be LightGray, setting it to Brushes.Transparent makes the text unreadable.

Is there a way to set the selected text colour (forecolor) dynamically (based on a bound property)?

Or is there a better way to do this? Is it possible to have a MultiTrigger with a PropertyTrigger (like on IsSelected) and a DataTrigger (on our ForeColorFlag)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following style to your application resource, or the resources of your DataGrid:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Foreground}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

You are telling it to set the foreground color to the color it already was, which I guess is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style inside resources of your application or wherever it is necessary:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
          </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Won't this force the foreground property (the text colour) to be black when it's selected? I need it to not change the underlying text colour! The underlying text colour could be red or grey, I don't want it to go black when it's selected.

Comment: Then you can take help of dynamic resources depend's on your themes... Like <setter property="Foreground" value={DynamicResource textForegroundColor}>... I would suggest you to study this ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The foreground colour varies depending on the row. There must be a simpler way to set the Selected text colour not to overwrite the underlying colour.

Comment: The fore colour (text colour) defaults to white (I just double checked this). The default selection style is blue background, white text. I need some way to not overwrite the underlying text colour (forecolor) style when a row is selected.